# strange scanf argument

Tags: c

What will be occurred in this lines of code :

```
char Message[10];
scanf("%s%*",&Message,'?');
```

Why it reads two lines and then it will igonre the second line ?

It gives me first line as output when i use

```
`printf("%s",Message)`
```

Comment: "Strange" how?? "It reads two lines and igonre[sic] second one"? What?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [scanf reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/): An asterisk prefix to a type (i.e. a "%*[type]" format string, where [type] is a scanf type specifier, e.g. `d` or `s`) means that the value read is to be ignored; so the '?' parameter is actually just there as a "placeholder", to indicate that `scanf` will read two values.

The format string shown in the question ("%*") is, however, invalid (it is missing the type specifier), meaning that the shown call will result in undefined behavior.

Comment: `%*` is not a complete format specifier (missing the letter for type of conversion to ignore, for example `s`), so the whole call to `scanf` is invalid. And this is the reason for my downvote. Other voters: fact-check!